# Rally Pie chart listener not working

Tags: highcharts, rally

I created one doughnut chart however I cannot get the listener working on it due to some strange reason. I tried adding the listener within the series and outside as well, but could not get this to work.

Can anyone please do let me know what might I be missing here
Below is the code snipet

var chart = Ext.create('Rally.ui.chart.Chart', {

```
                    chartConfig: {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'pie',
                             /*events: {
            click: function(event) {
            console.dir("Clicked");
            }
            }*/ /*THis works but it generates events only on click of the text on the pie charts*/
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Defects per Release Status '
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Total Defects per project'
                            }
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                shadow: false,
                                center: ['50%', '50%']
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: '%'
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Teams',
                            data: teamData,
                            size: '60%',
                            dataLabels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                                },
                                color: 'white',
                                distance: -40
                            }
                        }, {
                            name: 'Defects',
                            data: defectData,
                            size: '80%',
                            innerSize: '60%',
                            dataLabels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    // display only if larger than 1
                                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    },

                      listeners: {
    click: {        
        element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
        fn: function(){ console.log('click el'); }
    },
    dblclick: {
        element: 'body', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
        fn: function(){ console.log('dblclick body'); }
    }
}

                });
```

Comment: can you try to reproduce the same in a jsfiddle, that will actually help us to understand what has went wrong

Comment: I can definitely try, however I somehow feel that this might be related to way Rally interprets rather than highCharts, since this is a Rally Custom App

Comment: Thanks I made some progress through http://jsfiddle.net/xXwax/. I will continue with further development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a click event to chartConfig.plotOptions as shown below should work. You may see a full example of Rally TestCaseResults by Verdict pie chart in [this repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/pie-and-column).

```
plotOptions : {
     pie: {
       allowPointSelect: true,
       cursor: 'pointer',
       point: {
         events: {
           click: function(event) {
           var options = this.options;
           alert(options.name + ' clicked');
         }
       }
},
```